# FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h not found when I try to build in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an app made in ionic, but when I try to build in xcode I receive:

> ## import  FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h file not found

this is my plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.11.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.3 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-sim 1.3.3 "SIM"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.4.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
```

My podfile don't have any dependency.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you run the command `pod install` in your `platforms/ios/` directory?